# How to keep a HTTP long-polling connection open?

Tags: c++, network-programming, long-polling

I want to implement long polling in a web service. I can set a sufficiently long time-out on the client. **Can I give a hint to intermediate networking components to keep the response** **open?** I mean NATs, virus scanners, reverse proxies or surrounding SSH tunnels that may be in between of the client and the server and I have not under my control.

A download may last for hours but an idle connection may be terminated in less than a minute. This is what I want to prevent. Can I inform the intermediate network that an idle connection is what I want here, and not because the server has disconnected?

If so, how? I have been searching around four hours now but I don’t find information on this.

- Should I send `200 OK`, maybe some headers, and then nothing?
- Do I have to respond `102 Processing` instead of `200 OK`, and everything is fine then?
- Should I send `0x16` (synchronous idle) bytes every now and then? If so, before or after the initial HTTP status code, before or after the header? Do they make it into the transferred file, and may break it?

The web service / server is in C++ using Boost and the content file being returned is in Turtle syntax.

Comment: A [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) perhaps? That option should have been quite clear if you just read the HTTP 1.1 specification.

Comment: I meant to keep the *response* open. (I updated my question accordingly.) I think that a long download may last hours, while no response may cause a time-out after less than a minute. For example, PuTTY has some TCP keep-alive option. I wonder if something like this can be realized for HTTP as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this doesn't guarantee that the connection *and the response* will remain open . That's why libraries that implement long polling have to be able to reconnect after a large timeout.

Comment: @Paramaeleon getting long polling right is *not* easy. It's especially difficult on the server side, where a bad implementation can cost a lot in resources. Why don't you use a library for this? Why not use some *other* technique like WebSockets or forever frames?

Comment: Sure, reconnecting is a must. I am wondering if it is possible to keep the required reconnects seldom, by letting the intermediate network know that the server side has not yet gone offline.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using HTTP and implementing the server in C++ is both a project requirement. I know it may occupy resources, but low latency is a high piority in the project. I will keep WebSockets in mind as a an option if long polling will show not to bring the desired effects.

Comment: @Paramaeleon it won't. Long polling is the *fallback* transport when websockets and forever frames fail, because it's the most expensive for the server. As for resources, you *won't* get low latency if you use a lot of resources or end up with leaks. That's why I said that you should use a library *like* SignalR. Don't try to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will examine these in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force proxies to extend their idle timeouts, at least not without having administrative access to them.

The good news is that you can design your long polling solution in such a way that it can recover from a connection being suddenly closed.

One such design would be as follows:

1. Since long polling is normally used for event notifications (think the Observer pattern), you associate a serial number with each event.
2. The client makes a GET request carrying the serial number of the last event it has seen, either as part of the URL or in a cookie.
3. The server maintains a buffer of recent events. Upon receiving a GET request from the client, it checks if any of the buffered events need to be sent to the client, based on their serial numbers and the serial number provided by the client. If so, all such events are sent in one HTTP response. The response finishes at that point, in case there is a proxy that wants to buffer the whole response before relaying it further.
4. If the client is up to date, that is it didn't miss any of the buffered events, the server is delaying its response till another event is generated. When that happens, it's sent as one complete HTTP response.
5. When the client receives a response, it immediately sends a new one. When it detects the connection was closed, it creates a new one and makes a new request.

When using cookies to convey the serial number of the last event seen by the client, the client side implementation becomes really simple. Essentially you just enable cookies on the client side and that's it.

Comment: What you describe is correct and it is what I am already planning to do. I know that I cannot trick a hard time-out in some proxy. But, for example, PuTTY has some TCP keep-alive option. I wonder if something like this can be realized for HTTP as well − to “fake a running download”. It may still hit some max transfer time-out, but it should circumvent no-data time-outs.

Comment: @Paramaeleon TCP keep-alive is not terribly useful in this scenario, as `a)` you can't control its interval and `b)` it's not about prolonging the connection but rather about detecting a situation when your peer died (rebooted) without notifying you. While it may be possible to prolong an HTTP connection by sending small no-op chunks of a response over time, such tricks are not robust in the presence of a proxy.

Comment: @Paramaeleon In fact, another way to prolong the connection is by putting a limit on how long you delay your response for. When that limit is reached, you issue an empty response and the client submits a new one. Still, there is always a possibility that a proxy's timeout will be set to an even smaller value. Finally, I fail to see the point in trying to prolong a connection when your system is robust against it being suddenly closed.